# Getting "Range Check Error" in Delphi 7 when clicked on menu item projects >> Edit project constants

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am getting "Range Check Error" in Delphi 7 when clicked on menu item projects >> Edit project constants...I'm not able to attach reference image as this is my first post...please help.

Comment: Please add more detail. What is that menu item? I've never seen it. Is it part of the standard IDE, or is it from one of your add-ons.

Comment: If you have an image, put it on an image sharing site and tell us the link. We'll edit the image into the question.

Comment: FWIW, Google says it's an DKLang thing.

Comment: OK, so this appears to be a defect in DKLang. Your recourse for action is to contact the DKLang developer and ask for help.

Comment: Press Alt+P in Delphi 7 IDE it will open Projects menu, in that list second last item named "Edit project constants..."

Comment: I don't have D7 installed, but there is no such menu item in D2007, and I can't remember having ever seen one in one of my Delphi IDEs. So I guess it is some component set or expert you have installed. Do you have installed DKLang, for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That menu item does not exist in standard Delphi. It originates in one of your IDE add-ins. You need to work out which add-in is responsible for the menu item, and then contact the add-in developer to report the defect.

Comment: Thanks....it's add-in from DKLang component....will need to contact DKLang developer.